# Print the elements of an array with certain rules

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

My title might be confusing but I do not know what to put. Currently, I am trying to learn about RBF-Kernel-PCA from a book and I am at the code where they load the dataset and then plot the dataset with code like below:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform 
from scipy import exp 
from scipy.linalg import eigh 

from sklearn.datasets import make_moons 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, random_state=123)
plt.scatter(X[y==0, 0], X[y==0, 1],
            color='red', marker='^', alpha=0.5) 
plt.scatter(X[y==1, 0], X[y==1, 1],
            color='blue', marker='o', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

I dont understand why they use X[y==0,0] and X[y==0,1]. What is the y and why can it be performed with y== 0, 1? What is the 0 and 1 actually? Please kindly explain in detail or share your knowledge. I am still a beginner so I might not be able to understand deep explanations. Thank you

Edit**

I understand that the "y" is the label from the dataset now. But I dont get why they use 0,1. 0 stands for label 0 but what about 1?

Example,

```
X[y==0,1] # here label is 0 so what about the 1?
X[y==1,1] # here label is 1 so what about the 1?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more like `X[(y==0), 1]`, note the parentheses. Specifically this code is selecting each row where `y==0`, and then the 1 is the column (the second column). The comma separates the axes of the `X` array. For example, let's have these arrays `X` and `y`:

```py
In [100]: X = np.array([[5, 4], [3, 2], [1, 0]])

In [101]: X
Out[101]:
array([[5, 4],
       [3, 2],
       [1, 0]])

In [102]: y = np.array([1, 0, 0])
```

Now `y==0` will give you a boolean array, the same size as `y`, but with `True` or `False` respectively where the values are equal to zero:

```py
In [103]: y == 0
Out[103]: array([False,  True,  True])
```

Now you can use this boolean array to select the rows, via [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```py
In [104]: X[y == 0]
Out[104]:
array([[3, 2],
       [1, 0]])
```

Note that it selected the second and third row, which were the indices where `y` was equal to zero. And if I wanted only one of these columns, I would just add another index:

```py
In [105]: X[y == 0, 1]
Out[105]: array([2, 0])
```

So here a full description of this indexing operation is "select the rows according to the indexes where `y` is zero, and select the second column."

Comment: Thank you so much sir. this is really easy to understand.